# quitting a void method on a timer

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nstimer

I have a method that runs concurrently with recording a video. When the method ends it fires off a chain of other methods that continues until the recording ends. I want to be able to press a button to stop the recording prematurely that also exits the method at the same time. The way I'm currently trying to do it is with an NSTimer that checks to see if the recording is still happening, and if it isn't, it stops playing audio and should also call return to stop the method.

```
-(void) method
{
    self.stopTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.05 target:self selector:@selector(checkRecording) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    // Stuff happens
}

-(void) checkRecording
{
if (isRecording == NO)
    {
        if (player.playing == YES)
        {
            [player stop];
        }
        return;
    }

}
```

This stops the audio immediately but the method continues to run until it's done. It doesn't call the next method in the sequence, which is a step in the right direction, but I need it to stop immediately. My only theory is that it's because I'm not calling return inside the actual method that I want to stop and instead in a different method, but even if that's the case I'm not really sure how to fix that because as far as I know timers can only point to other methods and I can't just tell it what I want it to do inside of the method that I want to stop. And if that's not the issue then I'm really not sure why this isn't working.

Comment: If you want the timer to stop firing you need to invalidate it.

[self.stopTimer invalidate]

Answer (score 0):

If a timer is valid you can invalidate it (that stops the timer).

I'm not sure if all the checking is really necessary (& the last line) but I do it currently that way:

```
if ( myTimer != nil && [myTimer isValid] )
{
    [myTimer invalidate];
    myTimer = nil;
}
```

EDITED:

```
if ( [myTimer isValid] )
{
    [myTimer invalidate];
    myTimer = nil;
}
```

Comment: Checking `!= nil` is indeed unnecessary; `[nil isValid]` evaluates to `NO`.

Answer (score 0):

> My only theory is that it's because I'm not calling return inside the actual method that I want to stop and instead in a different method

Your theory is correct. `return` ends the function or method it is in, and none other. It pops the current function's context off the stack and returns execution to the calling function.

> I'm not really sure how to fix that because as far as I know timers can only point to other methods and I can't just tell it what I want it to do inside of the method that I want to stop

We can use objects to store state and use that state to control the flow of our program. That state can be continually updated and checked. With a long-running task that needs to be cancelled in response to changes in that state, the state must be updated in parallel with the task. Since you say the timer works for stopping audio, but that the work done in `method` doesn't, I'm assuming that `method` is performing its long-running task asynchronously already.

This need to do an asynchronous long-running task (or series of tasks) in the background, with the possibility of cancellation, is nicely matched to the `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue` classes.

You can perform your work inside `NSOperation` objects, either via implementing methods or blocks. Implement your code to check if the operation has been cancelled at all appropriate times, and bail out as soon as that happens.

Below is an example that hopefully matches your use case. It was created in an iOS app 'empty application' template an everything is in the application delegate. Our app delegate keeps track of the state necessary to make the decision of whether to cancel or not, and also schedules a timer to poll for changes in that state. If it does determine that it should cancel, it delegates the actual cancellation of work to the operation queue and its operations.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"


@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (nonatomic) BOOL shouldStop; // Analogous to your isRecording variable
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSOperationQueue *operationQueue; // This manages execution of the work we encapsulate into NSOperation objects

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Typical app delegate stuff
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // Start our long running method - analogous to method in your example
    [self method];

    return YES;
}


- (void)method
{
    // allocate operation queue and set its concurrent operation count to 1. this gives us basic ordering of
    // NSOperations. More complex ordering can be done by specifying dependencies on operations.
    self.operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    self.operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;

    //  We create three NSBlockOperations. They only sleep the thread a little while,
    //  check if they've been cancelled and should stop, and keep doing that for a few seconds.
    //  When they are completed (either through finishing normally or through being cancelled, they
    //  log a message
    NSMutableArray *operations = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        //  Block operations allow you to specify their work by providing a block.
        //  You can override NSOperation to provide your own custom implementation
        //  of main, or start, depending. Read the documentation for more details.
        //  The principle will be the same - check whether one should cancel at each
        //  appropriate moment and bail out if so

        NSBlockOperation *operation = [[NSBlockOperation alloc] init];

        //  For the "weak/strong dance" to avoid retain cycles
        __weak NSBlockOperation *weakOperation = operation;

        [operation addExecutionBlock:^{
            //  Weak/strong dance
            NSBlockOperation *strongOperation = weakOperation;

            //  Here is where you'd be doing actual work
            //  Either in a block or in the main / start
            //  method of your own NSOperation subclass.
            //  Instead we sleep for some time, check if
            //  cancelled, bail out if so, and then sleep some more.
            for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
                if ([strongOperation isCancelled]) {
                    return;
                }
                usleep(10000);
            }
        }];

        //  The completion block is called whether the operation is cancelled or not.
        operation.completionBlock = ^{
            //  weak/strong dance again
            NSBlockOperation *strongOperation = weakOperation;
            NSLog(@"Operation completed, %@ cancelled.", [strongOperation isCancelled] ? @"WAS" : @"WAS NOT");
        };

        [operations addObject:operation];
    }

    //  Set up a timer that checks the status of whether we should stop.
    //  This timer will cancel the operations if it determines it should.
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(checkShouldKeepGoing:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    //  Use GCD to simulate a stopped recording to observe how the operations react to that.
    //  Comment out to see the usual case.
    double delayInSeconds = 5;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        self.shouldStop = YES;
    });

    //  Add the operations to the operation queue, exeuction will start asynchronously from here.
    [self.operationQueue addOperations:operations waitUntilFinished:NO];
}


//  If we should stop, cancel the operations in the queue.
- (void)checkShouldKeepGoing:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    if (self.shouldStop) {
        NSLog(@"SHOULD STOP");
        [timer invalidate];
        [self.operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Man, this is way more complex than I thought it would be, but thanks! I'll take a closer look at what you've posted and see if I can figure out how to make it work for what I need; I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @lunadiviner I hope I didn't over-complicate my example. It's actually not terribly difficult, but I needed to throw together some timers and blocks to try to model your problem, hopefully those don't obscure the main point too badly. One thing I forgot to recommend is to check out Apple's [concurrency programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). And let me know if you have any questions or if I can clarify my answer.